# Multithread Orientado a Objetos em C++11 Nativo?

Tags: c++, thread, multithreading, c++11

Como é implementado o `Multithread Orientado a Objetos` em `C++11`? em java isso é possível através das Extensão da Class `Thread` / Implementação da interface `Runnable` e sobrescrevendo o Método Run de ambas. Em `C++11` não consegui identificar uma forma `Nativa`de fazer isso. Quais são as construções equivalentes as de `Java` a `wait`, `notify`, `notifyAll`, `synchronized`, `yield`, `isAlive`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A partir do padrão C++11 foram introduzidas funcionalidades referentes a programação concorrente. Estas funcionalidades podem ser encontradas nos arquivos:

- `<conditional_variable>`
- `<future>`
- `<mutex>`
- `<thread>`

Nesse arquivos você tem acesso a diversas funções e classes que oferecem o básico para você poder construir aplicações concorrentes.

Respondendo especificamente as suas dúvidas com relação aos equivalentes em Java:

Primeiramente temos que lembrar que ideologicamente C++ e Java são linguagens bem diferentes, em C++ orientação à objeto é apenas mais uma ferramenta e normalmente não é imposta ao usuário. Sendo assim, para a utilização das bibliotecas de concorrência não existe a mesma exigência de criar uma classe que herde de `Runnable` ou `Thread`.

Esse é um exemplo em C++ da criação de uma `std::thread` que executa a função `thread_main`:

```
std::thread t{ thread_main };
```

`thread_main` pode ser qualquer coisa que possa ser invocada como uma função que não recebe parâmetros e não retorna nada.

Alguns exemplos de implementação:

```
// Função comum
void thread_main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Ola de outra thread.\n";
    }
}

// Lambda
auto thread_main = []() {
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Ola de outra thread.\n";
    }
};
```

Outras diferenças da implementação de threads em C++:

- `std::thread` começa a executar imediatamente. (Como se chamasse o método `start` de Java no construtor)
- antes de um objeto do tipo `std::thread` ser destruído é obrigatório que se chame um dos seguintes métodos:

  - `std::thread::join`: bloqueia e espera que a thread termine de executar.
  - `std::thread::detach`: libera a thread para continuar executando independentemente.

Com relação aos métodos de Java, só existe uma equivalência direta:

- `Thread.yield` = `std::this_thread::yield`

Em C++ as funcionalidade de notificação (sinais) são implementados por uma classe separada, `std::condition_variable`. Sendo assim, temos as seguintes equivalências:

- `Object.wait`:

  - Java

    ```
    Object obj;
    // ...
    obj.wait();
    ```
  - C++

    ```
    std::condition_variable obj_cond;
    std::mutex obj_mutex;
    object obj;
    // ...
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(obj_mutex);
    cond.wait(lock);
    ```
- `Object.notify`:

  - Java

    ```
    Object obj;
    // ...
    obj.notify();
    ```
  - C++

    ```
    std::condition_variable obj_cond;
    object obj;
    // ...
    cond.notify_one();
    ```
- `Object.notifyAll`:

  - Java

    ```
    Object obj;
    // ...
    obj.notifyAll();
    ```
  - C++

    ```
    std::condition_variable obj_cond;
    object obj;
    // ...
    cond.notify_all();
    ```

Para as outras funcionalidades que você perguntou, não existe uma equivalência direta:

- `Thread.isAlive`: `std::thread` não oferece um método para verificar se a thread ainda esta sendo executada, para obter esse comportamento seria necessário usar um dos métodos da seção anterior ou `std::promise<T>`/`std::future<T>`.
- `synchronized`: Em C++ você precisa fazer isso manualmente, você pode criar um `std::mutex` associado a cada objeto que você gostaria de utilizar como objeto monitor no `synchronized` de Java. Um exemplo dessa conversão:

  - Java

    ```
    Object obj;
    // ...
    synchronized (obj)
    {
        // Faz algo com obj aqui
    }
    ```
  - C++

    ```
    std::mutex obj_mutex;
    object obj;
    // ...
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(obj_mutex);
        // Faz algo com obj aqui
    }
    ```

Referências:

- [Lista das bibliotecas de concorrencia](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) (Em inglês)
- [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) (Em inglês)
- [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) (Em inglês)
- [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) (Em inglês)